# How to generate thumbnails automatically with uniform size from orginal images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have orginal image from post. I now want get it to create thumbnail but the image is blurred because of resizing.

You can see example from this image :

[image]

How can i do that with javascript/jquery?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're willing to use CSS rather than jQuery, you could investigate the `background-size:cover` declaration.

```
<div style="background:url(/path/to/your/image.jpg);background-size:cover;height:200px;width:170x;"></div>
```

This ensures that both portrait and landscape orientation pictures will fit into whatever size `div` you decide.

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/8V4f6/

Comment: It is not solution i want. You can see with other size : http://jsfiddle.net/happi/8V4f6/1/ . It seems just croping images from top to bottom, left to right and then resizing. Actually, i need another method. However, thank for your help.

Comment: @happi I don't see how your last fiddle is any different from the sample images in your question, what's the expected result then?

Comment: @happi if it's the uneven cropping that is the problem, try `background-position: center center` - http://jsfiddle.net/8V4f6/2/

Answer (score 1):

From the images you posted, I assume you already know how to force the size using HTML or JavaScript (e.g., `<img width="32" height="32">`, `myImage.style.width="50%"`, etc.).  Since you said, "image is blurred because of resizing,", I think you're asking how to resize with better quality.

You can't control the quality of resizing done in the browser.  (A few years ago, I did a comparison and found big differences in quality between browsers.)

For better quality, your only option is to create separate images using a better algorithm (often referred to as "resampling").  Personally, I use either [ImageMagic](http://www.imagemagick.org) (any platform) or [IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.com/) (Windows).

With ImageMagick:

```
mogrify -path MY_THUMBNAILS -thumbnail 32x32 *.jpg
```

That's also quicker to download for the user.  In contrast, if you were to simply use HTML or JavaScript, the user's browser would still have to download the full resolution file of every image, even if it looks small on the screen.

I realize that isn't the answer you asked for.  If you really must do everything in JavaScript, I suppose you could write a web service that resizes images and returns thumbnails.  I don't think that's what you were after.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same image  with a lower height and width attribute as your thumbnail image.

```
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/AziqE.png" height= "10" width = "10" alt = "test image"/>
```

Comment: Nope. You don't understand my question. You can see example from above question.